# Usage middleware and plugin Nuxtjs

Tags: node.js, vue.js, middleware, nuxt.js

I have a problem with the good (and correct) construction of the application of Nuxt.js:

I read the documentation, but I do not understand when to use plugins, middleware. And what is the difference between plugins and middleware (within 
 Nuxt.js)?

I want use external source (easyrtc), but I do not know how best to load this source: as plugin or as middleware (easyrtc has client-side and server-side modules).
I without problems connected server modules as plugins:

for plugin
`export default ({ app }, inject) => { app.easyrtc = server; }; )`
for nuxt.config.js
`{ src: '~plugins/easyrtc/server/easyrtc_server.js', mode: 'server' }`

I plan to create my own middleware-wrapper for work with easyrtc-server:

My middleware-wrapper load plugins of easyrtc-server, and work with easyrtc.
Do I correctly represent the interaction of middleware and plugins?

Maybe I cover too much discussion area.
So if you have questions about my problem, I will try to answer.